# Is the angular ngRoute 'Controller' declaration necessary?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

After reading both the api and the developer guide, I still don't understand the functionality provided by declaring 'controller' in a given route.  Right now I just have my controllers declared as ng-controller directives in my views.  Is ngRoute simply providing an alternative method?

To make my question explicit in code, see below:

```
--Index.html
...
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
</body>

--View.html
<div id="myView" ng-controller="MyController">
...
</div>

--Route.js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [ require('angular-route') ]);

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  console.log('this gets executed as I would expect');
}])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: '/Index.html' })
    .when('/view', { templateUrl: '/View.html' });
    // below line makes no difference as an alternative to above
    //.when('/view', { templateUrl: '/View.html', controller: 'MyController' });
}]);
```

Comment: I don't know all details, but at least ng-route also provides `resolve` functionality.

Comment: when you specify controller in the routes, you don't need to specify the ng-controller tag in the view..

Comment: @TechMa9iac - then why have it?

Comment: It's upto you @Phil Olson. See, few people feel it good to wire up view and controller in code, others do it in HTML. i personally do in HTML. you can go the way you prefer..

Comment: Alright - I just wish that was explicit in the documentation.  If you want to make that an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to define controller for a view.

1. Either in the controller declaration in the ng-route
2. in the ng-controller for the view.

Either one is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should pick one option over the other since using both will actually give you **duplicate** controllers, i.e. both will be used.  If you're using `Routes`, then you can specify a few additional properties such as resolve which has been mentioned in the comments and this will allow you to perform an action, or supply supplementary data etc.

Take a look at this article, [Using Resolve In Angular](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx), for more information.

Also, you should look into using [Controller As](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/), which sets you up for future proofing.  John Papa has a few blogs and videos where he praises the use of Controller As and using the `var vm = this;` style syntax, take a look [*here*](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/).

Also, as a side note, you should use the `.otherwise` in your routes as this will capture any requests that are invalid and at least serve up a valid page from your site.  You can see this in the [routeProvider documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

Comment: I actually tested using both and the code was not executed twice.  Is that simply undefined behavior?  I could double check my test case too if you think that shouldn't be the case. Edit: And thanks for mentioning 'Controller As'.  I had forgotten about it in the midst of all the "getting started with angular" articles out there.

Comment: Strangely, I was watching a PluralSight video last night where this side-effect was shown as an example...It was Clean Code by John Papa, if you have a subscription.

Comment: I do not - but I definitely appreciate the tip.

Comment: @PhilOlson, I think you can use the site for free for a few days or a time limit of videos - worth a look. p.s. I gave far more valid info than the accepted answer?! :)

Comment: I know many people love pluralsight, and I've heard good things about lynda as well.  I tend not to learn via those venues though - even if in some circomstances it tends to work better.  And about more valid info: you did, but you didn't answer the question directly.  The question was "Is the angular ngRoute 'Controller' declaration necessary?".  You gave valid and helpful information, but I should make future readers aware of the direct answer to that.

Comment: I just had the duplicate controller problem, which was solved by having only one of ngroute declaration or html declaration. Seems to me to be a bug in angular, i.e I can't see any valid reason for having two controller constructor calls. Might expect ngroute to inspect the view it's given and see if it already defines the same controller. Also, seems to me @christiandev has the better answer as this is quite a serious problem (e.g duplicate resource fetches, etc).