# AngularJS controller works but does not load html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, ng-view, plunker

I have some unexpected problem with my controller, which occured during building 1st angular project, just like in here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-ZQHv70BCw&t=2119s
The problem is my link to home page does not load, it has no effect whatsoever, even when console shows the message and does not return any errors. I test this on plunkr.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" ng-app="computer">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Computer Solutions</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- The justified navigation menu is meant for single line per list item.
           Multiple lines will require custom code not provided by Bootstrap. -->
      <div class="masthead">
        <h3 class="text-muted">Computer solutions</h3>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-justified">
            <li><a href="#/main">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

<div ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>

      <!-- Site footer -->
      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2016 Company, Inc.</p>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module("computer",['ngRoute'])


.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
  when('/main', {
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
 });

}])
.controller('MainCtrl', [function(){
  console.log('this is mainctrl');
}]);
```

and main.html

```
this is main.
```

Thanks in advance, Michał

Comment: Do you have a Plunkr for us ?

Comment: Route will work on localhost that is it require xmlhttprequest call so put your on any server then test it will work

Comment: Do you have the correct path to your html file? For example, should it be './main.html' ?or '../main.html'?

Comment: [link]https://plnkr.co/edit/WIwc78eIaWKQpgyFCmfq Here it is @daan.desmedt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed your imports to version `1.4.8`. The version you had included seems to have problems on `$route` definition without a `otherwise` :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```

I've also added the other states, and should all be working.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/main', {
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  }).
  when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'about.html',
  }).
  when('/services', {
    templateUrl: 'services.html',
  }).
  when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'contact.html',
  })
}])
```

See working version : https://plnkr.co/edit/ebB3GAnoDSunsHK4bpme

Comment: Well, this version does work when clicked on Main, but still does not when clicked on other links. The strange thing is I did same thing as u did and console shows logs only when clicked on Main. I use http-server on ubuntu, I have no idea where a problem might be ;(

Comment: Update: It works, I just forgot to rerun http server after commiting some minor changes, thank you Sir for all your help @daan.desmedt

Answer (score -1):

I guess u have mentioned Controller(MainCtrl) in html and in routeProvider as well. Try removing one of the places.
check https://stackoverflow.com/a/27314659/3821223